# BATCH script to find string from file and append like variable in file name

Tags: script, batch-file

Hi guys i need little help with batch script...
from file something.txt which contain

```
data
data
LastLogedUser=John.Doe
data
data
```

i want to find the string LastLogedUser= and append the text after that (in this case "John.Doe" like a variable in copy of other file...
Like this but something is wrong in my  code:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I "LastLogedUser=" something.txt') do set "uniuser=%%a"  
echo User is: %uniuser%   
copy fpr_log.txt c:\fpr_log%uniuser%.txt
```

Comment: It's not clear what is the issue. What is expected and what you got instead?

Comment: In the end i want to get copy of file fpr_log in C:\  with name fpr_logJohn.Doe.txt ... in my case doesn't find and append John.Doe... i get only c:\fpr_log.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Something is wrong in my code

`findstr /I "LastLogedUser=" something.txt` is returning the whole line from the file:

```
> findstr /I "LastLogedUser=" something.txt
LastLogedUser=John.Doe
```

So your `for` loop needs to use `=` as a delimiter and get the **second** token in order to extract `John.Doe`.

I've also added some `"`s in case there are spaces in the user name ...

Corrected batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr /I "LastLogedUser=" something.txt') do set "uniuser=%%a"  
echo User is: %uniuser%   
copy fpr_log.txt "c:\fpr_log%uniuser%.txt"
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [For - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

Comment: This work thx... but only on Windows 10 1803 ... i try this on workstation with Windows 10 1809. And nothing happen WTH?

Comment: @DaimlerChrysler {shrug} I don't have Windows 1809 to test with.

Comment: I think i find the problem... i als use a variables for date and time
copy fpr_log.txt c:\fpr_log_%date%_%time:~0,2%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,2%s_%uniuser%.txt

when i removed  variables for date and time everything work normal on 1809... %date%_%time:~0,2%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,2%s 
but what the solution to use date and time like variables in windows 10 1809 any ideas?

Comment: @DaimlerChrysler See my answer [Windows batch, Different regional setting, Rename directory YYYYmmDD\_HHmmSS](//superuser.com/a/1262349) for the correct way to get date and time independent of current locale settings.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like get current text in variable and add text after like:

```
variable: exvariable
append: john.doe
result: exvariablejohn.doe
```

?
Try:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('echo %variable%') do set variable=%%iappendtext
```

Did I get it right?

Comment: Simply `set "variable=%variable%appendtext"` or `set  "variable=%variable%%append%"` does the job. No need for a `for` loop.